# Keep prompting the user a number until it falls into a certain range

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a program which will read a number input from the user.

The program currently reads the number and I use while loop for reading, checking it is between 1 and 20. As long as the number isn't between 1 and 20 the loop should keep going.

I am having trouble getting this to work and also having trouble with the calculation of the user's number (I want to multiply it by 50).

I want the program to output to be on screen.

Here is my code so far:

```
var choice;
var price = 50;

choice = parseInt(prompt("Please input number of days for your Bus tour",""));

while(choice < 1 && choice > 20){
    alert("You cannot have a bus tour for less than 1 day or over 20 days!");
    return true;
}
else if(choice > 1 && choice < 20){
    alert("Your total price for your bus tour is "+(choice*price));
}
```

I am a bit of a n00b at JavaScript and can't find the answer I am looking for. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: A variable cannot be `< 1` ***and*** `> 20` at the same time. `while..else` does not exist; only `if..else`. You're missing the condition for then the value is *exactly* `1` or *exactly* `20`. You probably want to ask for a new number inside the loop.

Comment: You need to describe what error / problem exactly you're getting.

Comment: Thanks for the note deceze, I am a bit of a noob at JS.

Comment: It says im getting an illegal return statement. Any other help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ShadowMinion try to replace `while` with `if`

Comment: @C0dekid.php Yeah I tried that but still getting illegal return statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `do` loop here, as we want to prompt the user in any case right at the start. So it's a bit more logical if we don't do the validity check as the first thing, but as the last thing in the loop.

Next I would recommend using a flag variable that can be `true` or `false`, depending on the user's input. This makes the code easier to read and helps reduce the chance of bugs.

We also need to break the loop when the user clicks "cancel" in the prompt.

```js
var choice = 0;
var price = 50;
var isValid = false;

do {
    choice = prompt("Please input number of days for your Bus tour","");
    if (choice === null) break;  // user clicked "cancel"

    choice = parseInt(choice);
    isValid = choice >= 1 && choice <= 20;

    if (isValid) {
        alert("Your total price for your bus tour is "+(choice*price));
    } else {
        alert("You cannot have a bus tour for less than 1 day or over 20 days!");
    }
} while ( !isValid );
```

Comment: Thanks for this :), this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution for your question:

```
var choice;
var price = 50;
choice=parseInt(prompt("Please input number of days for your Bus tour",""));

if(choice < 1 || choice > 20){
    alert("You cannot have a bus tour for less than 1 day or over 20 days!");
}else{

alert("Your total price for your bus tour is "+(choice*price));  
}
```

You don't need to use while loop just simple if else condition will be enough for this problem.

Comment: Thanks, noted for future reference. :)